# SSIS package is failing without any error message?

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, ssis

i have a parent package and a child package. in the parent package there is foreachloop task. for each data in my table should pass to child package. in child package there are so many insert task are there. the final result is a xlm file. i have created this using flat file destination. where the name i given as 'abc.xml'.

while executing the parent it is going to the child and after one execution the execute package task and foreachloop is failing.  and giving a warning like this.

Warning: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.

Could any one help me to fix this?
Thanks and Regards

Comment: Add Package Logging to your packages to collect more information.

Answer (score 1):

try to isolate which child package is causing you problems.  You can either

- Use the logs
- Run each child package in turn until you hit the error
- View the resulting tables to identify which point is failing (i.e. 5th table in the loop is populated, however the 6th is still empty)

Once you know where and what the problem is, you can decide whether to

- fix it
- accept a higher level of errors (by changing the "maximum error count" property on package)
- pass the failed records to a new "LoadFail" table to review and manually process after the package has completed